# Stored Procedure With Array parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have phone in my arrays such

```
 string phones="05763671278,05763271578,04763125578"
```

How can I result of all phone in that array?(for this case there must be return 3 records)

```
SELECT * FROM Accounst where Phone in ('05763671278,05763271578,04763125578')
```

but it return null although this phone in table

Comment: use a splitter [from this site](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and inner join to the result set is one way, assuming your "array" is a comma separated parameter you are passing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the quotations. Do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounst where Phone in ('05763671278','05763271578','04763125578')
```

It returns `NULL` because it looks for a `phone number` as:

```
'05763671278,05763271578,04763125578'
```

and obviously this is not a phone number.

Comment: this give error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '

Comment: Wow... duplicate answer for the win. Original.

Comment: @Theesisia can you look this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682595/stored-procedure-with-array-parameters-csharp-to-mssql

Answer (score 1):

if phone is a string (varchar or char) you want:

```
Phone in ('05763671278','05763271578','04763125578')
```